# Tool for quick Kubernetes cluster configuration

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I have a bunch of a manifest files for Kubernets configuration.
Is there some tool which can be used to quickly provision Helm charts and manifest files for Kubernetes cluster deployed as a standalone cluster ow AWS/Azure?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Minikube on your machine. Minikube is also a Kubernetes Engine which can be deployed in your Local Machine

- If you are using Windows -> use docker desktop Kuberentes
- If you are using Ubuntu -> use [Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/)